# Which of the following field properties are correct?

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $\omega = \cos{\frac{2\pi}{10}}+i\sin{\frac{2\pi}{10}}$.
>   Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\omega^2)$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$. Then
>
> 1. $[L : \mathbb{Q}] = 10.$
> 2. $[L : K] = 2$.
> 3. $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$.
> 4. $L = K$.

$\omega^5=-1$. Hence $\omega$ satisfies $x^5+1=0=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$.
So the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$. $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=4$

Now $(\omega^2)^5=1$.Hence $\omega$ satisfies $x^{5}-1=0\implies (x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$.
So the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$. $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 4$

Now
$
[L : \mathbb{Q}] = [L : K] [K : \mathbb{Q}]
\implies 4 = 4[L : K]
\implies [L : K] = 1
\implies L = K.
$

So only $3,4$ are correct. Can someone please verify my answer.

Comment: How do you know $x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1$ is irreducible?

Comment: it is so over $\Bbb Q$ as $1,-1$ are the only roots possible and none wrks

Comment: That doesn't show that you can't write it as a product of two quadratic factors.

Comment: One way would be to use that $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=\Phi_5(-x)$, and that $\Phi_5(x)$ is irreducible.